# css/html submenu displaying behind rather than on top of other page content

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu for my website:

here is the HTML

```
<ul id="trans-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

as you can see it has a dropdown (submenu) under the link but the sub menu is displaying under the page content below the menu.

how can i make it display the sub menu OVER the page content rather than behind?

here is the CSS:

```
#trans-nav {list-style-type: none; height: 40px; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#trans-nav { list-style-type: none; height: 40px; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#trans-nav li { float: left; position: relative; padding: 0; line-height: 40px; }
#trans-nav li:hover { background-position: 0 -40px; }
#trans-nav li a { display: block; padding: 0 15px; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; }
#trans-nav li a:hover { background-color:#F36F25; color: #eeeeee; }
#trans-nav li ul { opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 8em; background: #EEEEEE; list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#trans-nav li:hover ul { opacity: 1; }
#trans-nav li ul li { float: none; position: static; height: 0; line-height: 0; background: none; }
#trans-nav li:hover ul li { height: 30px; line-height: 30px; }
#trans-nav li ul li a { background: #EEEEEE; }
#trans-nav li ul li a:hover { background: #666666; color:#EEEEEE; }

#trans-nav li { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; }
#trans-nav li a { -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; }
#trans-nav li ul { -webkit-transition: all 1s; }
#trans-nav li ul li { -webkit-transition: height 0.5s; }
```

also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charliejsford/SAXmG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be defining any `z-index`. Without it, elements that appear later in the page will appear on top.

To fix this, I suggest adding `position:relative` to your list's styles, and then you can also add `z-index:1000` or some other suitable number.

Comment: where should i add the position relative?

Comment: To the list's styles, like I said.

Comment: sorry, do you mean to the #trans-nav li ul ?

Comment: I mean your root list, `#trans-nav` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not defining any z-index should not be a problem, and i don't think it's wise to define useless z-index everywhere.

With sample CSS code you post there, your menu should lie on the top of any static element that follow it, because your menu is positioned and the rest of your page is not.

So if you're submenu goes behind the page content, the page content you're talking about must be positioned too, and it may be your true problem.